# Импорт проекта в jupyter notebook

Tags: python, импорт, jupyter-notebook

Я хочу импортировать проект `coordinates` в `weather_api_service`.

Если я делаю это через `import`, выдает ошибку

```
import coordinates 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 import coordinates 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coordinates'
```

Все проект находится в одном файле [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: импортировать можно только файлы типа .py

Comment: но можно вот так -> https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html

Comment: Команда import увидеть ваш файл, если у него будет разрешение py, а сейчас разрешение у вас юпитера ipynb.

Comment: мне кажется, самым простым вариантом для вас будет сохранить notebook через меню "Download as" (если у вас Jupyter Lab, то через "Save andExport as... executablescript") в обычный .py файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут поискал, потыкался, нашёл библиотеку `nbimporter`, только для её работы необходимо провести несколько дополнительных операций над самим файлом Jupyter Notebook.

Откройте файл `.ipynb` в текстовом редакторе, найдите тэг `metadata`:

```
...
"metadata": {
  "language_info": {
   "name": "python"
  },
  "orig_nbformat": 4
...
```

Встройте в него тэг `"kernelspec"`, получиться как-то так:

```
...
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "name": "python"
  },
  "orig_nbformat": 4
...
```

В моём случае книга называется `helloIAMJupyter.ipynb`, вот её содержимое:

```
print('hello')

def solve_this(var):
    return var+2
```

Далее я создал `test.py`, импортировал в него `nbimporter` и `helloIAMJupyter`, исполняя из него функцию `solve_this` с параметром `2`:

```
import nbimporter
import helloIAMJupyter

print(helloIAMJupyter.solve_this(2))
```

При исполнении в консоли следующее:

```
4
```